# Why does my android activity always start scrolled to the bottom?

Tags: android, layout

Whenever I start this activity, it always starts bottomed out--scrolled all the way to the bottom. I am not doing anything weird in the activity OnCreate (or anywhere for that matter) that I would expect to change the scroll position. I have tried setting focus to the topmost focusable control, and the scrollto method, but neither of them are working. Besides, none of my other activities has this problem. Here's the layout:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edit_refresh_update_header"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\n"
            android:textSize="4sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Variable:"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/edit_refresh_variables_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\n"
            android:textSize="4sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Network:"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/widget1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioButton
                android:text="Web"
                android:id="@+id/edit_refresh_update_rb_web"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="NetRadioButtonSelected"
                android:checked="true"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:text="Socket Server"
                android:id="@+id/edit_refresh_update_rb_socket_server"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="NetRadioButtonSelected"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\n"
            android:textSize="4sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Socket server request type:"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/edit_refresh_socket_server_req_types_spinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\n"
            android:textSize="4sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Socket server body:"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/edit_refresh_update_ss_body"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\n"
            android:textSize="4sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Url:"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/edit_refresh_update_url"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\n"
            android:textSize="4sp"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Save refresh update"
            android:id="@+id/edit_refresh_save_btn"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:onClick="SaveRefreshUpdate">
        </Button>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\n"
            android:textSize="4sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: How exactly did you try to change focus?

Comment: using the fulscroll method as described below and the scrollto method as also described below. I don't necessarily mind fixing it this way, but there must be a reason why it is starting like that and I'd rather fix it by correcting that.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

When Android starts an activity, some control needs to take focus. When there's no designated control to take focus, the system chooses the first eligible control that wants focus.
If you set the following property in your LinearLayout - `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` your `LinearLayout` will be focused on start and your activity won't scroll to `EditText` in the bottom.

Comment: Not working in my GridLayout. I have a GridView in the middle of the layout, and it gets the focus every time.

Comment: Scratched my head for a complete day and couldn't find as to why it was happening in just one particular activity and I still don't understand since I have not enabled focus on any view. But thanks to you, I managed to fix this issue. It'd be great if someone could throw some light as to what could be the possible reason since there is nothing new I'm doing in the new activity.

Comment: An important note: this is to be added as property to the `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView`, not to the scroll view itself.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev very important note. Should be added to the answer. By the way, thanks for that :P

Comment: It is literally mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 35):

Instead of polluting items in your layout, you can add this into your Activity/Class:

```
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    scrollView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
    scrollView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
```

This way it isn't an element within your scrollView getting focus, it's your scrollView as a container which get's the first focus, moving onto the child view's after this.

Comment: Partially works for me when I trying to set ListView height based on children inside ScrollView

Comment: This helped! (while the same attributes in xml did not work..)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thx

Comment: It did work for me, but I added this line:
scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP)
Both separately didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code:

```
scroller.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        scroller.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN); 
    } 
});
```

[N:B] [referance link][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832701/scrollview-alawys-scrolling-to-the-bottom)

Comment: its a good option but it simulates a jerk after opening so not a good user experience i think

Answer (score 4):

**Add these two lines in your** `ScrollView`

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with what devmiles.com said.

> If you set the following property in your LinearLayout - android:focusableInTouchMode="true" your LinearLayout will be focused on start and your activity won't scroll to EditText in the bottom.

If you call requestLayout() on a view at the bottom of your linear layout it might steal the focus from your top most view. So just call requestFocus() on the top most view in the linear layout after calling requestLayout() on a lower view.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but you could experiment with

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
sv.scrollTo(0,0);
```

in your `onCreate` to manually scroll it to where you like it to be.

Comment: you saved me , everyone says ScrollView.FOCUS_UP but It has a side effect, if you are using edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener  then it will get focus automatically to the edit text.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried use fullScroll method ?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#fullScroll(int)

```
yourScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin Android development, if you want to do @Graeme solution then:

```
// Set Focus to ScrollView
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.scrollView);
scrollView.FocusableInTouchMode = true;
scrollView.DescendantFocusability = Android.Views.DescendantFocusability.BeforeDescendants;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make it not focusable in onCreate()

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
```

and use

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new ....){
 ......
  editText.setFocusable(true);
  editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
  editText.requestFocus();

  showSoftKeyboard(); //Use InputMethodManager to open soft Keyboard

 ......
 };
```

and it will not scroll down to Edittext next time, a fragment or activity is created.

Answer (score 0):

`scrollView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_UP)` solved my problem when I wanted the top view to be visible.
Specifying direction parameter to the method `requestFocus(int direction)` is a good way to control the `ScrollView` position. More details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestFocus(int)).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a `VideoView` inside a `ConstraintLayout` inside a `ScrollView`. The `VideoView` was always stealing focus, and [there are issues with it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36955106). Solution is to use a `TextureView`. Hopefully this helps someone, it cost me an hour at least :)

Answer (score 0):

with `Kotlin` and `ViewBinding` u can add this in your `fragment` or `activity` :

```
binding.mainScroll.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
binding.mainScroll.descendantFocusability = ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS
```