# Android: Seekbar changes form position

Tags: android, android-xml, android-seekbar

I have a Seekbar that when I touch the seekbar and update it's position, my form will reposition itself seemingly "magically". For instance, if the seekbar is at the top of my form when I scroll through the form, and I begin to change the seekbar position, the entire form will scroll back up and put the seekbar consistently to the bottom of the form.

I have the Parent form in a scroll view. Nested inside is a linear layout with all of my relative layouts inside of that. Here is the relevant code. If more code is needed please let me know.

XML:

```
                <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Turns_Box"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Prev_Box"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Turns_Text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Turns_Text"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/Turns_Value"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/Turns_Text"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:max="25"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Turns_Value_Text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/Turns_Value"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
        // Actual Turns
    SeekBar actualTurnsValue = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.Turns_Value);
    turnsValueText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Turns_Value_Text);
    turnsValueText.setFocusable(false);
    actualTurnsValue.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                turnsValueText.setText(progress + 5 + "  Full Revolutions");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            graphicAttributes.setActualTurns(Integer.toString(seekBar.getProgress() + 5));
        }
    });
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears that I left a vague clue as to what was going on. All of my views had no "focusable" set. So when I created my first scrollview, and no control was set to focus, Android chooses the first eligible control that wants focus. This caused some weird functionality in my code. Found it on SO from an answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9690661/3109213

So I just simply set my nested LinearLayout to have:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```